# Truth behind the Stand Alone Complex—a copy of a copy?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-sac

After a while from watching *GITS: S.A.C. 2nd GIG* and according to the Stand Alone Complex as defined under [different terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Baudrillard#Simulacra_and_Simulation) by the French philosopher Jean Baudrillard in the idea of the Stand Alone Complex is a copy of an original copy:

> Simulation, Baudrillard claims, is the current stage of the simulacrum: all is composed of references with no referents, a hyperreality. Progressing historically from the Renaissance, in which the dominant simulacrum was in the form of the counterfeit—mostly people or objects appearing to stand for a real referent (for instance, royalty, nobility, holiness, etc.) that does not exist, in other words, in the spirit of pretense, in dissimulating others that a person or a thing does not really "have it"—to the Industrial Revolution, in which the dominant simulacrum is the product, the series, which can be propagated on an endless production line; and finally to current times, in which the dominant simulacrum is the model, which by its nature already stands for endless reproducibility, and is itself already reproduced.

Does this not make the concept of the Stand Alone Complex its own copy of a previous work?

Comment: wat...........?

Comment: I edited it to make a bit more sense @ShotgunNinja -- Leaving out my personal notes which did not really belong in there.

Comment: @Neko_Kun are you asking for about references the second order of simulacra in from the series?

Comment: Yes, maybe there are a few that I missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the anime, it was stated that the Stand Alone Complex is the spawning of copies without an original. The concept was borrowed from Baudrillard and you can in fact argue that the popularity of *Ghost in the Shell* is overshadowing his work, and this would be an example of second-order simulacra.