# What was the inspiration for "Many copies, no original"?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-sac

In GITS SAC 2nd GiG, what was the original inspiration for the concept of "many copies, no original"?

Does the concept have a name in real life? Or was it just a concept the writers created just for the show?

Comment: It's too complicated for me to write about it in English, but it's based on [Salingers short story "The Laughing Man"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Laughing_Man_(Salinger)) and the idea is called [Simulacra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacra) which was investigated by [Jean Baudrillard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Baudrillard#Simulacra_and_Simulation). Whoever wants to write an answer, can look it up. Maybe [this question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3323/122) helps you, too.

Comment: Note: The term "Stand Alone Complex" is also used, but not very often. I've only seen it to describe Anonymous yet.

Comment: @looper: That answers my question. I thought it dealt with economics and how various people can solve the same problem without knowledge of one another. I was extremely off. If you want, you can just copy/paste your comments as an answer... so I can give you credit for answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a comment first, but converted to an answer.

The hole idea is called [Simulacra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacra) and was investigated by [Jean Baudrillard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Baudrillard#Simulacra_and_Simulation). The original inspiration was [Salingers short story "The laughing Man"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Laughing_Man_(Salinger)).

The concept is now also known as "Stand Alone Complex", but it's not frequently used, except (for example) for the group [Anonymous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_(group)).

Also, [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3323/122) may have some additional information.